# Icons are not shown in moderncv

Tags: moderncv, cv, icon

I'm writing my personal CV with `moderncv` and the `classic` specification, but I cannot display the icons relating to personal information such as mobile phone, mail, address etc. 
Here's my code before the `\begin{document}` row:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}

\usepackage{moderncviconsawesome}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\moderncvicons{awesome}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%\nopagenumbers{}
%\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}
%\usepackage[italian]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\setquotestyle{english}

\usepackage[top=1.8cm,bottom=1.3cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.2cm}
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{9cm}

\firstname{Name}
\familyname{Surname}
\title{PhD}
\address{My address}   
\phone[mobile]{+1234567}
\email{mymail@test.com}
\extrainfo{mysecondmail@test.com \\
    Date of birth: AAA}
\photo[58pt][0.1pt]{pic.jpeg}
```

And here's a screenshot:
[image]

So the icons don't appear and I don't understand what is missing in my code or in its dependencies.

Comment: Does the log file show errors? Add the first error to your question please (copy it from the log file and paste it to your question).

Comment: There are no errors...

Comment: The icons show up for me when I use your code. Can you post your log at some pastebin site? I'm curious how it differs from mine.

Comment: I'm working on Overleaf and I don't know why but I can't download the log, sorry. I think the problem is in one of the dependencies/packages but I don't understand where the error could lie. I started from a template, so I suspect that the files have been modified but I have difficulty understanding which ones to look at, there are too many of them.

Comment: Did you fond the solution?

Comment: No, sorry. I didn't add them.